# Firebase "Blaze" projects limit, multiple env and Spark plan outbound requests

Tags: firebase

I'm working with Firebase and quite enjoying it so far.

I'm working with DEV, PREPROD and PROD environments for each of my projects. For each env I've had to create a distinct firebase project.
Since my app is using Algolia and Cloud vision API, I apparently have to be on the Blaze plan because Spark plan doesn't allow outbound requests and Cloud vision API calls (if I'm correct).

The thing is we're limited with the numbers of Blaze projects we can have at the same time. Above a certain amount (6 or 7, I think) we have to request a "billing quota increase" and explain why we need more (sounds odd but ok).
So I did, but now Firebase is asking for a $50 transaction to increase the number of Blaze projects I can have.

So I have several questions:
- Am I right to think that in Spark plan I can't call the Algolia API in my cloud functions or call Cloud vision API ?
- Are these $50 a payment to unlock new projects slots or just credits that will be available if needed ?
- If I need even more projects in the future will I have to pay even more credits ?
- How am I supposed to handle separate environments on Firebase without creating a different project each time ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: "Am I right to think that in Spark plan I can't call the Algolia API in my cloud functions or call Cloud vision API?" -> Yes **for the Algolia API**. See https://firebase.google.com/pricing/ which explains that "The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services" (mouse hover on the question mark close to the "Cloud Functions" title).

Comment: Yup I saw that but just wanted a confirmation before asking the real questions. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the Spark plan, with Cloud Functions, you can only make outgoing connections to services that Google fully controls.  Algolia will not work.

Please [read the FAQ](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en) regarding the number of projects you may have and the payment being asked to create a new project:

> **Why am I being asked to make a payment for more projects?**
>
> You may be asked to make a payment if your request for more projects
>   indicates that you need projects that will use paid cloud services.
>   The payment can be applied to any charges you incur in the future and
>   will be visible as a credit in your account.
>
> This payment is required to ensure paid services will be available for
>   the projects you requested in the quota increase request form. This is
>   a common requirement, because Google Cloud Platform services are paid
>   (e.g., Compute Engine, Cloud SQL, and BigQuery).
>
> The payment required varies depending on your billing history, the use
>   cases described in your request form, the number of projects you
>   request, and other factors.

So, the $50 you are being asked to pay will apply as credit to your project billing.

You should definitely create new projects for each environment.

Comment: So how about the Flame option for 25$ a month?